# Como transformar um arquivo INI em um Array?

Tags: php, ini

Como posso transformar um arquivo `INI` em um `array` em PHP?

Exemplo:

```
[database]
host = localhost
password = sabe_de_nada_inocente
port = 3306
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se usar `parse_ini_file` ele irá interpretar sem as sessões, ficará algo como:

```
Array
(
    [host] => localhost
    [password] => sabe_de_nada_inocente
    [port] => 3306
)
```

Mas se aplicar o segundo parâmetro `parse_ini_file('arquivo.ini', true);` assim terá isto:

```
Array (
   [database] => Array (
        [host] => localhost
        [password] => sabe_de_nada_inocente
        [port] => 3306
    )
)
```

Se o conteúdo vier de uma string use então `parse_ini_string`, assim:

```
<?php

$data = '[database]
host = localhost
password = sabe_de_nada_inocente
port = 3306';

print_r(parse_ini_string($data, true));
```

### Alguns detalhes que mudaram:

- **PHP 5.3.0**

  Adicionado o terceiro parametro, o `scanner_mode`, aspas simples (apostrofos) são usados para setar a variavel e deixam de fazer parte do valor delas.

  Hashs # não devem ser usadas para comentários, use `;`, usar o hash vai causar um warning, pois esta em desuso, apesar do `parse_ini_*` ainda interpretar o hash como comentário.
- **PHP 5.6.1**

  Adicionado o modo `INI_SCANNER_TYPED`, no terceiro parametro.
- **PHP 7.0.0**

  Hashs finalmente não são mais usados como comentários e causa um erro de parse se tentar usar.

### Usando o modo scanner_mode

Se tiver um .ini assim:

```
[foo]
baz = true
bar = false
foobar = On
foobaz = Off
```

E fizer isto:

```
<?php

var_dump(parse_ini_file('meu.ini', true));
```

Irá retornar isto, string com valor 1 se `true` ou `On`, ou string vazia se `Off` ou `false`:

```
array(1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["baz"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["bar"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["foobar"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["foobaz"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

Note que se usar aspas ou apóstrofos ele não irá fazer o parse para 1 ou vazio, semelhante ao `INI_SCANNER_RAW`:

```
baz="true"
bar="false"
foobar= "On"
foobaz="Off"
testnumer="0"
```

Se usar `INI_SCANNER_RAW` (PHP 5.3.0+)

```
<?php

var_dump(parse_ini_file('meu.ini', true, INI_SCANNER_RAW));
```

Não irá fazer o parse de On, Off, true e false, serão todos string "literais":

```
array(1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["baz"]=>
    string(4) "true"
    ["bar"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["foobar"]=>
    string(2) "On"
    ["foobaz"]=>
    string(3) "Off"
  }
}
```

Se usar `INI_SCANNER_TYPED` (PHP 7) ele irá tratar `On`, `off`, `true` e `false` como `boolean`:

```
<?php

var_dump(parse_ini_file('meu.ini', true, INI_SCANNER_TYPED));
```

Retorna isto:

```
array(1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["baz"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["bar"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["foobar"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["foobaz"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
}
```

Comment: Olha, essa informação da "seções" foi importante, hein. +1

Answer (score 4):

Use a função [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php). Caso exista 'campos' com o mesmo nome, o último entrará como chave no array. Para evitar essa situação, passe `true` como segundo argumento, assim o array será separado por sessões.

config.ini

```
[database]
host = localhost
password = sabe_de_nada_inocente
port = 3306
[ftp]
user = admin
password = admin1234
```

php:

```
$arr = parse_ini_file('config.ini', true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

Saida:

```
Array
(
    [database] => Array
        (
            [host] => localhost
            [password] => sabe_de_nada_inocente
            [port] => 3306
        )

    [ftp] => Array
        (
            [user] => admin
            [password] => admin1234
        )

)
```

Sem o informar o segundo argumento o retorno é:

```
Array
(
    [host] => localhost
    [password] => admin1234
    [port] => 3306
    [user] => admin
)
```