# Como manipular a string vinda de um arquivo .reg exportado do regedit?

Tags: php

Como abstrai os valores desses parâmetros individuais e armazenar em uma variável, ou usar para comparar com outra variável ?

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\leroLero]
"parametro1"=valor
"parametro2"=valor
"parametro3"=valor
```

Comment: É uma pergunta sobre PHP mesmo, quer pegar os dados do .reg e ler em um script php? PS: o downvote não é meu.

Comment: sim ler em PHP e comparar no script .com outras variaveis .

Comment: estranho toda vez que ponho pergunta em vez de ajudarem ponham negativas ......  rssss

Comment: Talvez tenham negativado porque da maneira que pergunta é meio dificil de entender, eu mesmo tinha essa dificuldade no inicio, tem pessoas que tem facilidade para se comunicar verbalmente, mas não conseguem fazer também via internet.

Comment: Ele quer parsear os dados de um arquivo exportado do registro do windows.. a origem disso tudo veio desse post: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/226338 e tem outro bem confuso

Comment: Se for um arquivo ini pode começar com: [Como transformar um arquivo INI em um Array?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/155990/91)

Comment: é .reg  o arquivo !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ideia é simplificar indo direto ao ponto, fazendo um explode() grosserio para transformar cada linha num item de um array.

Em seguida fazer a leitura do índice que interessa.

Como os dois primeiros são meros ruídos, pule direto para o índice 3 que é onde encontra-se o primeiro parâmetro:

```
$data = 'Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\leroLero]
"parametro1"=valor
"parametro2"=valor
"parametro3"=valor';

$arr = explode('
', $data);

// Vai direto no índice 3, mas antes faz uma limpeza, removendo as aspas duplas.
// A função parse_str() auxilia na conversão do formato de query para variáveis
$val = parse_str(str_replace('"', '', $arr[3]), $param);

// Agora pode acessar de forma amigável o parâmetro que necessita.
echo $param['parametro1'];
```

Se precisar ler o `parametro2`, a posição é 4 (número da linha) e no momento de ler basta chamar `echo $param['parametro2'];`.

Claro que isso é um exemplo didático. Não faz nenhuma validação se o índice existe, etc. É bom criar consistência no script para evitar problemas.

Comment: Obrigado `Daniel Omine` , vou adaptar tudo aqui .

Comment: OK. Obrigado , `Daniel Omine` , pela sua Ajuda.  MUITO OBRIGADO.

Answer (score 2):

Creio que o formato seja bastante semelhante ao do `.ini` (claro que tem variações, mas isto é outra situação, para o código acima creio que seja semelhante), se realmente for parecido pode usar o `parse_ini_string`, claro que antes é necessário fazer usar `preg_replace` para remover algumas coisas, no **caso especifico** só precisei remover as aspas das chaves, exemplo:

```
<?php
$regfile = file_get_contents('arquivo.reg');

$regfile = preg_replace('#(\r|\n)"|"(=)#', '$1$2', $regfile);

$parsed = parse_ini_string($regfile, false, INI_SCANNER_RAW);

var_dump($parsed);
```

Um exemplo online: https://ideone.com/ZyHnS0

```
<?php

$reg = 'Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\leroLero]
"parametro1"=valor
"parametro2"=valor
"parametro3"=valor';

$reg = preg_replace('#(\r|\n)"|"(=)#', '$1$2', $reg);

$parsed = parse_ini_string($reg, true, INI_SCANNER_RAW);

var_dump($parsed);
```

Vai retornar algo como:

```
Array
(
    [parametro1] => valor
    [parametro2] => valor
    [parametro3] => valor
)
```

Então basta comparar assim:

```
if ($parsed['parametro1'] == 'valor') {
   echo 'algo aqui';
}
```

---

**Nota:** no caso não processei as sessões, esta como `false`:

```
 $parsed = parse_ini_string($reg, true, INI_SCANNER_RAW);
```

mas pode processar usando `true` acaso existam mais "sessões":

```
$parsed = parse_ini_string($reg, true, INI_SCANNER_RAW);
```

Então o resultado vai ser: https://ideone.com/wqyzXu

```
Array
(
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\leroLero] => Array
        (
            [parametro1] => valor
            [parametro2] => valor
            [parametro3] => valor
        )

)
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63377/discussion-on-answer-by-guilherme-nascimento-como-manipular-a-string-vinda-de-um)